# How to plot percentage labels in a bar plot per each legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a bar plot `geom_bar()` with ggplot, having a variable on x-axis and its count on Y-axis and the third to be as a legend and inside each legend the percentage of that legend from the count of Y-axis.

I'm using the built-in `mtcars` dataset as a reprex.

```
library (ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y= ..count..)) + 
geom_bar(aes(fill = factor(gear)))
```

I would like to have these percentages inside each legend, in a decent way if possible.

```
prop.table(table(eight$gear))

        3         5 
0.8571429 0.1428571 

prop.table(table(six$gear))

        3         4         5 
0.2857143 0.5714286 0.1428571 

prop.table(table(four$gear))
         3          4          5 
0.09090909 0.72727273 0.18181818
```

The documentation for this is listed [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_text.html)

But I reached the point where I can't put y as labels since I get it from a ggplot special start variable.

I'm sorry I can't upload images, since I'm a newbie having no sufficient reputation to post one, but running that mtcars code will generate what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably format the % labels separately and them add them as a second data frame to the chart.

Formatting using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
legendLabels <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, gear) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  arrange(cyl, desc(gear)) %>%
  mutate(percent = round(count/sum(count)*100,2),
         yPos = cumsum(count))
```

And the updated chart:

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y= ..count..)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = factor(gear))) +
  geom_text(data = legendLabels, aes(x=cyl, y=yPos-0.5, label=paste0(percent,"%")))
```

Giving this chart:
[image]

Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've applied that to my intended dataset and it worked, I've learned the yPos from you. Thank you!